# How does Pytest figure out that the monkeypatch fixture is for monkeypatching?

Tags: pytest, monkeypatching

Consider this simple example from [pytest's docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html)

```py
# contents of test_module.py with source code and the test
from pathlib import Path


def getssh():
    """Simple function to return expanded homedir ssh path."""
    return Path.home() / ".ssh"


def test_getssh(monkeypatch):
    # mocked return function to replace Path.home
    # always return '/abc'
    def mockreturn():
        return Path("/abc")

    # Application of the monkeypatch to replace Path.home
    # with the behavior of mockreturn defined above.
    monkeypatch.setattr(Path, "home", mockreturn)

    # Calling getssh() will use mockreturn in place of Path.home
    # for this test with the monkeypatch.
    x = getssh()
    assert x == Path("/abc/.ssh")
```

How does Pytest figure out that the param `monkeypatch` is the one for monkeypatching?

Comment: Fixtures are registered and injected *by name*, if you mean how is that implemented have you looked at the source code?

Comment: Ah, name. OK, that answers my question. Feel free to write your response as an answer so I can make it as correct. A link to the source code for the sake of completion would be appreciated as well.